# Continuous violineplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I not sure how to name it, but I need something like a "continuous violineplot" in python. Violineplot (like in seaborn) usually applies only for discrete classes and the frequency of the distribution density is drawn in direction of x-axis (and mirrored to look like a violine).

If I have e.g. points in time and at each point a density curve I could display the frequency as a color and than get a continuous stripe/tube/area around the average curve that shows the colored densities.

Is this possible in python?

Comment: Probably yes, but it may be hard to help you further without some more explicit input data, and what you expect from them.

Comment: Obviously you need to start by calculating the densities for each point. Then you could concatenate them to form an image. Then plot the image. But as it stands the question is too broad to be answered here, so it would be helpful to show at which point you're stuck.

Comment: Yes, I need to calculate the densities for each point. Than I could draw e.g. a colorbar at each point, but I thought there could be a more direct elegant way to do this. This approach seems to be totally "by hand". One could maybe also plot a spectrogram ... I will try this and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I built a solution for my problem, that I call "**sliding density plot**" (as long as there is no other name for this.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from   scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# Generate artificial data
tmin = 0
tmax = 1000
tN   = 1001
t0   = np.linspace(tmin,tmax,num=tN) # timesteps
y0   = np.sin(t0/1000.0*3.0*np.pi)

rmin = 0
rmax = 100
rN   = 101
r0   = np.linspace(rmin,rmax,num=rN) # runs of simulation (e.g.)

data  = [t0]
names = ['time']

for r in r0:

  name = "run%03i" % int(r)

  y1 = y0 + np.sin((r+t0/10.0)/100.0*np.pi)

  names.append(name)
  data.append(y1)

data = np.array(data)    
data = pd.DataFrame(data.T,columns=names)

# prepare kernel density estimation for each timestep
mybins_kde = np.linspace(-4,4,320)
sdens   = []
select = [x for x in data.columns if x != "time"]
data1  = data[select] 

# do kde
for i in range(tmin,tmax+1):
  y   = data1.iloc[i]
  bw  = (0.05/y.std(ddof=1))
  kde = gaussian_kde(y,bw_method=bw)
  h   = [kde.evaluate(mybins_kde)]
  sdens.append(h[0])

# prepare imshow
img = np.array(sdens).T

# start plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

# plot sliding density as image
plt.imshow(img,aspect='auto',cmap="gray_r",interpolation="bilinear",
               extent=[tmin,tmax, -4, 4],origin='lower')

# do some statistics               
mean = np.mean(data1,axis=1)
medi = np.median(data1,axis=1)
pc10 = np.percentile(data1,10,axis=1)
pc90 = np.percentile(data1,90,axis=1)

# plot statistics

plt.plot(t0,mean,label='Mean')
plt.plot(t0,medi,label='Median')
plt.plot(t0,pc10,label='10%-Percentil')
plt.plot(t0,pc90,label='90%-Percentil')

# beautify plot
plt.xlim(tmin,tmax)   
plt.legend(loc='upper right')         
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("value")
plt.title("sliding density plot for 100 sets of data")
plt.grid(linestyle='dashed',zorder=0) 

# plot some example densities
maxy    = 0
ax2     = fig.add_axes([0.16,0.14,0.25,0.25])
inset1  = np.array(sdens[150])
inset1 /= np.sum(inset1)
ax2.plot(mybins_kde,inset1,label="t=150")
inset2  = np.array(sdens[500])
inset2 /= np.sum(inset2)
ax2.plot(mybins_kde,inset2,label="t=500")
inset3  = np.array(sdens[980])
inset3 /= np.sum(inset3)
ax2.plot(mybins_kde,inset3,label="t=980")

# beautify inset plot
maxy = max([np.max(inset1),np.max(inset2),np.max(inset3)])
ax2.set_title("Example for densities at time t")
ax2.legend(loc="upper left")
ax2.set_ylim(0,round(1.5*maxy,2))

# show plot
plt.show()
```

Well, I sure, this is not the best and beautiful code, but it does what I need.

The resulting plot is here:
[image: sliding density plot]

Even if the data and the code is not optimal I think one can understand my poblem and my solution.